C++ Cmake: How to test if compiler exists and select it
How in Cmake test if compiler exists and if true then select it? Or some function to manually set desired compiler and it`s toolchain inside CMakeLists.txt, without external env variables nor additional toolchain files / cmake args? Some proper way?
Something like:
if(find_compiler("clang"))
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")

But will it automatically set properly other toolchain variables and etc? Also I had found deprecated Cmake module CMakeForceCompiler that looks like exactly what I want, but it is deprecated as I said and in my version of CMake this module doesn't exists.

if you want to set it manually:
When it detects C and C++ compilers, it looks for the CC and CXX variables. Set the path of clang to the CC and CXX environment variables
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
cmake ..


To check inside cmake file

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(test)

find_program(CLANG_CXX_PATH clang++)

if (CLANG_CXX_PATH)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++" CACHE INTERNAL "")
    message("Clang Found")
else()
    message("Clang not Found.")
endif()


I need to do this inside CMakeLists.txt, without manual modifications of external env vars

You can look at the clang flags, add them with find_program and check them.

does I need to put it before project() in CMAkeLists.txt or after? And also small question: does find_program(CLANG_CXX_PATH clang++) and find_program(CLANG_CXX_PATH "clang++") will be different?

I edited the code in more detail. The answer to the second question is; using quotation marks makes the code more secure. ( At least it feels that way)


How in Cmake test if compiler exists and if true then select it? Or some function to manually set desired compiler and it`s toolchain inside CMakeLists.txt, without external env variables nor additional toolchain files / cmake args? Some proper way? But will it automatically set properly other toolchain variables and etc?

What you can control the compiler selection using a combination of logic checks in CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test)

find_program(CLANG_COMPILER clang)
find_program(CLANGXX_COMPILER clang++)

if(CLANG_COMPILER AND CLANGXX_COMPILER)
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${CLANG_COMPILER}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${CLANGXX_COMPILER}")
else()
    message(STATUS "Clang compiler not found. Using the default compiler.")
endif()

...

You can practice with command-line arguments to specify the compiler when calling CMake commands: (automatically set properly)
> cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ ..

